# how to activate a textbox if I select an other option in drop down box

Tags: javascript, html

suppose I've a 3 options in a drop down box say red , blue, others.
    If a user select option as an others then below a text box should be visible to wrtie his own favourite color.
    I can populate the drop down box with colors but do not know how to bring textbox visible on selection of others in the 
    drop-down box. I know that using javascript it is possible to do but I am quite new to javascript. can anybody please help me 
    out??

This is the select option I am implementing in my html form

```
   <select name="color"> // color
    <option>pick a color</option>  
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="color" id="color" /></td> // this textbox should be hidden //until unless others is selected in the drop down box
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Below is the core JavaScript you need to write:

```
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckColors(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('color');
 if(val=='pick a color'||val=='others')
   element.style.display='block';
 else  
   element.style.display='none';
}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
  <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> 
    <option>pick a color</option>  
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
  </select>
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" style='display:none;'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its alright.. now I can understand a mistake in my question. I do not want to process a blank field. Here in this case text box is just invisible. I want it to be invisible and active in my form only in case i select others. I do not want to process a blank field because it will show an error while inserting vale in the database.

Comment: Sorry to chip in @Umesh... I can't get this to work because the text input negates the select options for some reason. HELP?
I mean, the javascript works and everything but it won't POST the values from the drop down... only the text input

Comment: @gavin Did you ever resolve the issue of the text input overwriting the select as I have the same issue?

Comment: @JohnHiggins I solved it by overwriting the text field content with the select value. It's just one more line in the Javascript under Else.

Answer (score 7):

Coded an example at http://jsbin.com/orisuv

HTML

```
<select name="color" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'> 
    <option>pick a color</option>  
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
</select> 
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" style='display:none'/>
```

Javascript

```
function checkvalue(val)
{
    if(val==="others")
       document.getElementById('color').style.display='block';
    else
       document.getElementById('color').style.display='none'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline:

```
<select 
onchange="var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
this.form.color[1].style.display=(val=='others')?'block':'none'">
```

I used to do this

In the head (give the select an ID):

```
window.onload=function() {
  var sel = document.getElementById('color');
  sel.onchange=function() {
    var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    if (val == 'others') {
      var newOption = prompt('Your own color','');
      if (newOption) {
        this.options[this.options.length-1].text = newOption;
        this.options[this.options.length-1].value = newOption;
        this.options[this.options.length] = new Option('other','other');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Umesh Patil answer have comment say that there is problem.
I try to edit answer and get reject. And get suggest to post new answer.
This code should solve problem they have (Shashi Roy, Gaven, John Higgins).

```
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckColors(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('othercolor');
 if(val=='others')
   element.style.display='block';
 else  
   element.style.display='none';
}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
  <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> 
    <option>pick a color</option>  
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
  </select>
<input type="text" name="othercolor" id="othercolor" style='display:none;'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
<select id = 'color2'
        name = 'color'
        onchange = "if ($('#color2').val() == 'others') {
                      $('#color').show();
                    } else {
                      $('#color').hide();
                    }">
  <option value="red">RED</option>
  <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
  <option value="others">others</option>
</select>

<input type = 'text'
       name = 'color'
       id = 'color' />
```

edit: requires JQuery plugin

Comment: shorter and neater, it's just what i use, i always have jquery attached anyway

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the answer. The OP might try this answer and end up getting many errors :P

Answer (score 0):

This will submit the right form response (i.e. Select value most of the time, and Input value when the Select box is set to "others"). Uses jQuery:

```
  $("select[name="color"]").change(function(){
    new_value = $(this).val();
    if (new_value == "others") {
      $('input[name="color"]').show();      
    } else {
      $('input[name="color"]').val(new_value);
      $('input[name="color"]').hide();
    }
  });
```