# Post Select Options To Database When "other" field is selected

Tags: javascript, html

i'm using the code below to display an input field when "other" option is selected.

It works perfectly when "other" is selected.

However, i am unable to post to database when any other option apart from "other" is selected.

The problem is the text input negates the select options.
Any idea how to go about this?

There's a question that attempts to solve the problem but i don't have enough reputation to comment [Stackoverflow.com/questions/9634783/how-to-activate-a-textbox-if-i-select-an-other-option-in-drop-down-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634783/how-to-activate-a-textbox-if-i-select-an-other-option-in-drop-down-box)

```
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckColors(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('color');
 if(val=='pick a color'||val=='others')
   element.style.display='block';
 else  
   element.style.display='none';
}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
  <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> 
    <option>pick a color</option>  
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
  </select>
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" style='display:none;'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is, that you have multiple form elements with the same name. This might work in some cases, but generally is a bad practice. Name them differently and let the code that processes the input handle the data.

If you really need an input with the name 'color' that holds the current color, here is a solution that should work:

```js
function checkColors(val) {
  var element = document.getElementById('color');

  if (val == 'pick a color' || val == 'others') {
    element.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    element.value = val; //make sure element always has the right value;
    element.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <select name="colorSelect" onchange='checkColors(this.value);'>
    <option>pick a color</option>
    <option value="red">RED</option>
    <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
    <option value="others">others</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="color" id="color" style='display:none;' />
</body>

</html>
```